# What is the default username and password on Comcast ARRIS gateways?

Tags: passwords, default-settings

Just wondering what the default username and password is on these black Comcast gateways?

Answer (score 0):

The username is `cusadmin`

For [business accounts](https://business.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/setup-manage-comcast-wifi-business-wireless-gateway/) the password is either `highspeed` or `CantTouchThis`

For residential accounts, the password is typically "password"